# Intersection of powers of prime ideals in the algebraic integers

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$\newcommand{\alg}{\overline{\mathbb{Z}}}$
Consider the integral closure $\alg$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. My question is:

> Is there a prime ideal $P \subset \overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ such that $\bigcap\limits_{n \geq 1} P^n \neq (0)$ ?

The property $\bigcap\limits_{n \geq 1} P^n = (0)$ holds in any noetherian domain (see Zariski–Samuel, *Commutative algebra, volume 1*, Chap. IV, §7, corollary 1, p. 216) but $\alg$ is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20574/what-sort-of-ring-is-the-integral-closure-of-mathbbz-in-overline-mathbb) to be a non-noetherian ring. However, it is a Bézout domain ; in particular it is Prüfer, so [apparently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687037) such an intersection is always a prime ideal.

Thank you!

Comment: Since $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is of Krull dimension $1$, this is equivalent (using the Bézout domain property) to $\bigcap\limits_{n \geq 1} P^n = P$, and so equivalent to $P^2 = P$.

Comment: How about the prime ideal generated by $2^{1/2^n}, n \geq 0$ ? Edit: I'm not sure if this is prime, sorry.

Comment: @cat : I was thinking the same thing. According to [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348789/can-the-square-of-a-proper-ideal-be-equal-to-the-ideal#comment750064_348801), it is maximal in $\Bbb Z[1/2^{1/2^n} : n \geq 1]$.

Comment: Since every element in $\overline{\mathbf{Z}}$ is an $n$th power, it's obvious that $P^n = P$ for every prime ideal. (Given $\alpha \in P$, write $\alpha = \beta^n$, then $\beta \in P$, so $\alpha \in P^n$). So yes, it's true for every non-zero ideal.

Comment: @Infinity : thank you for this elementary observation (I don't know how I missed it…). I would suggest that you can turn it into an answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thanks to this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820499/intersection-of-powers-of-prime-ideals-in-the-algebraic-integers#comment5816165_2820499) helpful comment, I can provide an answer.

**Proposition.**
Let $K$ be any algebraically closed field and $R \subset K$ be any subring. Let $A$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $K$ (we could just take an integrally closed subring $A \subset K$). Then every prime ideal $P$ of $A$ satisfies $P^n = P$ for all $n \geq 1$. In particular, $\bigcap_{n \geq 1} P^n \neq (0)$ iff $P\neq(0)$.

**Proof.**
Clearly, $P^n \subseteq P$ holds. For the reverse inclusion, pick $x \in P$. The polynomial $T^n - x$ has a root $y$ in $A$. Then $y^n = x \in P$ implies $y \in P$ since $P$ is a prime ideal. We get $x = y^n \in P^n$, as desired.
$\blacksquare$

We see that in our case $A = \overline{\Bbb Z}$ is a [Prüfer domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_domain) but not a Dedekind domain. Typically, the localizations $A_P$ are valuation rings, but not DVR (since $P^n=P \leq A$, one cannot just have an integer-valued valuation, as in the case of Dedekind domains...).

Comment: In particular, one cannot define ramification subgroups of the absolute Galois group of $\Bbb Q$ by imitating the definition from the number field case.

Comment: (One can only talk about ramification subgroups of the absolute Galois group of $\Bbb Q_p$).

Comment: (The valuation on the algebraic $p$-adic integers $O = \overline{\Bbb Z_p}$ is _not_ the valuation attached to the maximal ideal of $O$. Actually, the $p$-adic valuation on $O$ is not discrete, but takes values in $\Bbb Q$.)