# For a prime ideal $P,$ can $P^2 = P?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Suppose $P$ is a nontrivial prime ideal in an arbitrary ring. Can $P^2 = P?$ I suppose this might be true for some ring but I cannot think of an example...

Context: In a Dedekind domain, $P^2 \neq P$ as otherwise this would violate unique prime factorization of ideals. This is why I was wondering if equality could actually hold for some ring.

Comment: Consider the valuation ring of $\mathbb{C}_p$, the completion of algebraic closure of $p$-adic number. This is in the same spirit as the answer below.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348789/can-the-square-of-a-proper-ideal-be-equal-to-the-ideal, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820499/intersection-of-powers-of-prime-ideals-in-the-algebraic-integers

Comment: Typically, any prime in the ring of algebraic integers works (see second link above).

Comment: fyi: finitely generated idempotent ideals of commutative rings [are *principal*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/246091/242).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a commutative ring with a non-zero maximal ideal $M$ with $M^2=M$.
Let $k$ be a field and $R$ consist of "polynomials with rational exponents"
over $k$, that is each element of $R$ is a formal $k$-linear combination
of $x^r$ where $r\in\Bbb Q$ and $r\ge0$. The map $R\to k$ taking
$a_0+\sum_{r>0}a_r x^r$ to $a_0$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel
$M$ generated by the $x^r$ for $r>0$. Each of these is a square of an element
of $M$, so $M^2=M$.

Of course, this $R$ is non-Noetherian.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I was just wondering, what is the difference between a linear combination and a $\textit{formal}$ one?

Comment: @伽罗瓦 Formal combinations allow for infinitely many nonzero terms, linear combinations do not.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you!